# elasticsearch: cluster_block_exception TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm running spiders with multiprocess indexing, and I want to resolve this.

I'm always getting TOO_MANY_REQUESTS, is there a configuration I can change to allow for the threshold to be bigger for handling concurrent requests ?

this is the full error

```
2020-12-29 06:24:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://github.com/topics/python?o=desc&s=updated&page=5> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 90, in _parse
    return self.parse(response, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/src/app/xxxx/spiders/python_topic.py", line 85, in parse
    print_data(repository)
  File "/usr/src/app/xxxx/spiders/python_topic.py", line 42, in print_data
    repository.save(repository_doc)
  File "/usr/src/app/xxxx/model/repositories.py", line 18, in save
    repo.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/toute/document.py", line 90, in save
    saved_document = self.get_es(es).index(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 152, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, headers=headers, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 398, in index
    return self.transport.perform_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 392, in perform_request
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 358, in perform_request
    status, headers_response, data = connection.perform_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 269, in perform_request
    self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 315, in _raise_error
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(
elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(429, 'cluster_block_exception', 'index [xxxxxx] blocked by: [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];')
```

**UPDATE:**
Found flood disk watermark exceeded, while it doesn't seem to be exceeded!

```
elasticsearch_1  | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-12-29T06:40:51,701Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor", "cluster.name": "talks-cluster", "node.name": "n1_it", "message": "flood stage disk watermark [5gb] exceeded on [Z8G4W5UlQYy1HOk0JWGP7w][n1_it][/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0] free: 3.8gb[1.6%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only", "cluster.uuid": "uo5vK64tQoyfIeGiUhlStg", "node.id": "Z8G4W5UlQYy1HOk0JWGP7w"  }
```

output of df command

```
Filesystem    512-blocks      Used Available Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s6   489825072  22025208  12057544    65%  488254 2448637106    0%   /
devfs                385       385         0   100%     666          0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk1s1   489825072 413862176  12057544    98% 4477496 2444647864    0%   /System/Volumes/Data
/dev/disk1s4   489825072  17879464  12057544    60%       8 2449125352    0%   /private/var/vm
/dev/disk1s5   489825072  21349800  12057544    64%  487049 2448638311    0%   /Volumes/Ohne Titel
map auto_home          0         0         0   100%       0          0  100%   /System/Volumes/Data/home
```

Comment: What is the output of `_cat/nodes?v` and `_cat/indices?v`? Also can you check your ES logs to see if you're getting alerts of high disk watermarks being reached?

Comment: elasticsearch_1  | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-12-29T06:40:51,701Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor", "cluster.name": "talks-cluster", "node.name": "n1_it", "message": "flood stage disk watermark [5gb] exceeded on [Z8G4W5UlQYy1HOk0JWGP7w][n1_it][/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0] free: 3.8gb[1.6%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only", "cluster.uuid": "uo5vK64tQoyfIeGiUhlStg", "node.id": "Z8G4W5UlQYy1HOk0JWGP7w"  } it's a bit confusing the message

Comment: Can you also run the `df` command and update your question with the response you get?

Comment: It seems two of your disks are full. See my answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the error message you get, your disk is full

```
flood stage disk watermark [5gb] exceeded on [Z8G4W5UlQYy1HOk0JWGP7w][n1_it][/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0] free: 3.8gb[1.6%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only
```

You need to increase the disk space available for that node.

Comment: I solved it by disabled the disk watermark allocation

Comment: Well, you're just postponing the problem. You might not get the error anymore, but when the disk is full you won't be able to index anything anymore and your cluster might break down. Limits are there for a reason ;-)

Comment: Same rule applies within docker ref: https://github.com/drud/ddev-contrib/issues/146